# Permanent listener for incoming Queue Messages

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling, azureservicebus

I would like to do the following:

Create a DLL that is started once by a function and then listens permanently for new incoming Service Bus Messages.

In my opinion, my basic problem is to find a way to wait until the Event Handler can be executed. I want to do this permanently. So it should always be possible that the Event Handler can be executed.
Currently the GetPayloadAsync entry function terminates too fast.

In .NET the code looks like this:

Function GetPayloadAsync

```
   public static async Task GetPayloadAsyc()
    {

        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _tokenSource.Token;
        await ReceiveMessagesAsync(token));
        
    }
```

The ReceiveMessagesAsync function looks like this and registers the Event Handler:

```
static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        
        ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(AZURE_SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTIONSTRING, new ServiceBusClientOptions
        {
            TransportType = ServiceBusTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
        });
        
        ServiceBusSessionProcessor processor = client.CreateSessionProcessor(QUEUE_NAME, new ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions
        {
            MaxConcurrentSessions = 1,
            AutoCompleteMessages = false
        });

        // add handler to process messages
        //processor.
        processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
        
        // add handler to process any errors
        processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
        
        // start processing 
        await processor.StartProcessingAsync(token);                                          

    }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> In my opinion, my basic problem is to find a way to wait until the
> Event Handler can be executed. I want to do this permanently. So it
> should always be possible that the Event Handler can be executed.
> Currently the GetPayloadAsync entry function terminates too fast.

You can use the service bus trigger of azure function, which is a ready-made tool that can be used to process new incoming messages to the queue. And it will not terminate (this meets your requirement of ‘permanent’). You can follow this to create an azure function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. 
I need a solution via a DLL file. This DLL file will be integrated into our ERP system Dynamics NAV. In Dynamics NAV the Event Handler is defined which should be executed. 
So the DLL receives a Service Bus Message and fires an Event.